# Can I use use a Radeon 7750 with a 450 watt power supply unit?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, amd-radeon

I've been told that I can't use a Radeon 7750  video card because I will risk damage to my motherboard, which is an Asus m2n-mx se plus.  They said I should buy an Nvidia 630 GT. Should I buy a new 550-600 watt PSU or should I try the 7750?
My system  is a 3GHz dual core, Nvidia 9500 GT, 4 GB RAM DDR2.

Comment: Burn the motherboard? What? How?

Answer (score 3):

The Radeon 7750 graphics card [recommends](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7750/Pages/radeon-7750.aspx#3) a 400W or greater power supply. If your power supply is insufficient, it will not burn out your motherboard but instead, will either fail to boot up or your system will become unstable during load.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't burn out the motherboard. Exceptionally poor PSUs have fried under heavy draw and taken other components with them. Rare, especially now. But if we are talking about a $15 450w PSU from a company with a name no one knows, I would be suspicious and cautious.